# How to return more elements within a list as a string in Python

Tags: python

I have following elements within a list b['lemma'] within a function:

```
babicka
Marta
```

I want to *return* them as string like:

```
print(b['lemma'], end=" ")
>> babicka Marta
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `print(" ".join(b['lemma']))`

Comment: @not_speshal I tried that but it returns:
b a b I c k a
M a r t a

Comment: what does `print(b["lemma"])` output?

Comment: @not_speshal The output as above in the post. It's <class list>

Answer (score 1):

Use the [string `join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), like this:

```
return " ".join(b['lemma'])
```

Comment: I tried that but it returns: b a b I c k a M a r t a on two lines as a list

Comment: In that case, it would seem `b['lemma']` does not contain a list but rather a string

Comment: What does `print(repr(b['lemma']))` output?

Comment: It returns <class list>

Comment: I don't think that's a normal list; do you define a class of that name? What's the definition?